# How to get initial focus in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How to get initial keyboard focus on an Android compose app?

My view looks like

```
Parent { Child { Button} }
```

I tried implementing it in the Parent composable function....

```
FocusRequester is not initialized. Here are some possible fixes:
                                                                                                
                                                                                                   
1. Remember the FocusRequester: val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
                                                                                                   
2. Did you forget to add a Modifier.focusRequester() ?
                                                                                                   
3. Are you attempting to request focus during composition? Focus requests should be made in response to some event. Eg Modifier.clickable { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code woirks like a charm....

```
fun Modifier.requestInitialFocus() = composed {
    val first = remember { FocusRequester() }
    LaunchedEffect(first) {
        delay(1)
        first.requestFocus()
    }
    focusRequester(first)
}
```

Original:

This error does not happen when implementing it in the composable function, where the target element is a direct child....

So implementing it in the `Child` seems to be a solution....